# Show logging from imported class in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a Python project where I use both IDE and Jupyter to write Python code.

I have a class called `KnowledgeProcessor` in module `knowledge.knowledge_processor`, in that class I use `logging`.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()

class KnowledgeProcessor():
    def __init__(self):
        logger.info("That is a logging message")
```

Other than this file, I have a notebook file on the same project, in which I run

```
from knowledge.knowledge_processor import KnowledgeProcessor

k = KnowledgeProcessor()
```

What I expect to see is the logging from `KnowledgeProcessor`, but I don't see it. I've tried importing logging and changing default logger's level to debug and setting the stream to std, but it also didn't work.

Any ideas on what is wrong here?

Comment: Did you find out how? :)